# C++ constructor or recursive member function when using templates

Tags: c++, templates

I am writing a matrix library, and when I tested `the determinant of the matrix`, I found this error

I rarely use `templates` and can’t find the reason for the error

```
template<int n>
struct Vec{
    double data[n]{0};
    Vec() = default;
    explicit Vec(int value) { ... }
};

template<int row, int col>
struct Mat{
    Vec<col> data[row];
    explicit Mat() { ... }
    Mat(std::initializer_list<double> list) { ... }

    Mat<row - 1, col - 1> Minor(const int x, const int y) const{
        Mat<row - 1, col - 1> ret;
        ...
        return ret;
    }

    double Cofactor(const int x, const int y) const{
        return Minor(x, y).Det() * ((x + y) % 2 ? -1 : 1);
    }

    double Det() const{
        assert(row == col);
        if(row == 1 && col == 1) return data[0][0];
        double ret = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < col; ++i){
            ret += data[0][i] * Cofactor(0, i);
        }
        return ret;
    }
};
```

Unable to call `Det`

```
Mat<3, 3> matrix{2, 6, 3,
                 1, 0, 2,
                 5, 8, 4};
std::cout << matrix.Det() << std::endl;
```

The error message is as follows
[image]

Comment: What happens when `Vec<0>` is instantiated? It declares an array of size 0, which will throw a compile error. Think about your constructors logic.

Comment: You also seem to try to use subscripting on `Vec` (`return data[0][0];` for example) but `Vec` doesn't have a subscript operator.

Comment: Note that `std::array<double, N>` _can_ handle the special case `N==0`, unlike C arrays. Of course, initializing it with `{0}` is still an error as that has 1 intiializer, which is one too much.

Comment: @TedLyngmo `Vec` have a subscript operator,I omitted in the code above

Comment: @Veasky I see. Don't omit anything that is needed for the rest of what you put in the queston to compile. Make a [mre] (which means that we can copy and try to compile it without making any changes to it - and get the same error you got).

Comment: `assert(row == col);` - I think that should be a static_assert (compile time, not runtime in debug). And the subsequent `if` should be an `if constexpr` for similar reasons.

Comment: @Tharsalys This is indeed a problem, I currently add `assert` to the constructor to disable the zero vector

Comment: @Veasky disabling those instantiations will interfere with your overall logic, which requires that you be able to index at the `0th` position. Delineate the points where you're using the template arguments as size and index, and then add 1 to size and leave the index as is.

Comment: @Tharsalys I seem to understand the problem. The solution I can think of is to specialize `Mat<1, 1>` so that the recursion will end correctly here. But this is too much trouble, I have to write a version of `Mat<1, 1>` for all other member functions. Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your compiler supports at least C++17, then the solution is using `if constexpr`:

```
double Det() const{
        static_assert(row == col);
        if constexpr(row == 1 && col == 1) return data[0][0];
        else
        {
            double ret = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < col; ++i){
                ret += data[0][i] * Cofactor(0, I);
            }
            return ret;
        }
    }
```

This is C++ aspect of it. From an algorithmic perspective, computing determinants by definition (i.e. using the Kronecker method), as you do, leads to exponential complexity as a function of matrix size. Algorithms exist that are only a cube of matrix size.

Comment: Thanks! I changed the version of the project to C++17 and used `if constexpr`, which solved my problem